# Matlab to Python; Converting a hex-address to a decimal numpy array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, hex, decimal

Its probably done in a few lines but im currently stuck on the following problem:

I want to transfer a matlab operation to python. Matlab looks like this:

```
startAddress = hex2dec('00D00000');
address = hex2dec(flipud((reshape(dec2hex(address, 8), 2, 4))'));
```

So i get a 2D-vector with decimal numbers out of this. The closest i got to transfer this to python is the following:

```
import numpy as np

startAddress = int('00D00000', 16)
address = startAddress.to_bytes(8, 'little')
address = np.frombuffer(addressMsg, dtype=np.uint8)
address = address[0:4].reshape(4,1)
```

Is this equivalent? The rest of my code doesnt work properly and its quite complex so i wanted to figure out if my mistake is here or somewhere deeper.

Comment: Can you share the expected output/output from Matlab?

Comment: Sure! It should be a 4x1 double array (code formatting in comments doesnt break lines; imagine a [0;0;208;0] array, quite simple..) :
`address = 

     0
     0
   208
     0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB and Python solutions are equivalent.

The only difference I noticed is that MATLAB result is of class `double`, and in Python the ndarray elements are of type `uint8`.
(The type differences are probably not relevant).

There are small issues with the sample code you have posted that makes it non-executable:

- The MATLAB code should be: `dec2hex(startAddress, 8)` instead of `dec2hex(address, 8)`.
- The Python code should be: `np.frombuffer(address,` instead of `np.frombuffer(addressMsg,`.

---

You may get the same result using simpler code:

In MATLAB you can use `typecast`:

```matlab
address = double(typecast(uint32(startAddress), 'uint8')');
```

Sample code for testing:

```matlab
startAddress = hex2dec('12345678');
address = hex2dec(flipud((reshape(dec2hex(startAddress, 8), 2, 4))'));

address2 = double(typecast(uint32(startAddress), 'uint8')');
```

---

In Python you can use `struct.pack`:

```
address = np.frombuffer(struct.pack("<I", startAddress), np.uint8).reshape(4,1)
```

Sample code for testing:

```
startAddress = int('12345678', 16)
address = startAddress.to_bytes(8, 'little')
address = np.frombuffer(address, dtype=np.uint8)
address = address[0:4].reshape(4,1)

# Convert startAddress array of 4 uint8 elements (apply little endian format).
address2 = np.frombuffer(struct.pack("<I", startAddress), np.uint8).reshape(4,1)
```

---

MATLAB execution result:

```
address =

   120
    86
    52
    18

address2 =

   120
    86
    52
    18
```

Python execution result:

```
address
array([[120],
       [ 86],
       [ 52],
       [ 18]], dtype=uint8)

address2
array([[120],
       [ 86],
       [ 52],
       [ 18]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Youre right with the addressMsg instead of address part, of course, i wrote a function and forgot to mention that address = addressMsg. Trying out your simplification with struct right now :) thank you!